# Google Custom Search: Uncaught TypeError: google.search.Search.apiary15400 is not a function

Tags: google-programmable-search-engine

On my site I get the error :

> Uncaught TypeError: google.search.Search.apiary15400 is not a function

where the number changes on each page refresh.

I've already checked here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/CYN9lFK46hk, but did not find any double cse references in my own code.

Also, the ads that are being shown on the result page are somehow lightly grayed out.

I tried adding the script code to the head of the googlesearch.aspx page and the cse tag in the body, but that results in the same error.

How I inject the code:

in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var cx = '014868809914487598599:qtooouruo1q';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();

</script>
```

in body:

```
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading the script twice, causing the function to run twice and produce this error. An example line that is doubled up:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=014868809914487598599:qtooouruo1q"></script>
```

It's not the only line that's doubled - perhaps check your code for duplicates. Or if it's being injected check your document write calls to see if they've been doubled up.